# Props and Computations in Vue

Tags: vue.js, math, vuejs3, vite

I am having trouble with something seemingly simple: how do I use a prop, passed to my component, as the basis for some computation? As in --

```
export default {
    props: {
      officeConsumption: {
        type: Number,
      },
      commuteOutput: {
        type: Number,
      },
      savings: {
        type: Number,
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        drives: this.savings,
        flights: this.savings
      }
    },
```

And so on, except I want do something with savings (like Math.round) and use it in my template like {{ drives }}. I get as far as {{ savings }} i.e. using the original prop but am having trouble achieving the desired end result {{ Math.round(savings * / + some computation) }}. This is due 3 and Vite.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of using `computed` in Vue3. Under the hood, they're the same thing:

**1.** **Composition API `computed`**:

```js
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    officeConsumption: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const myComputed = computed(() => Math.round(props.officeConsumption));
    return {
      myComputed
    }
  }
})
```

Another flavor of the above is inside a `reactive()` object:

```js
import { defineComponent, computed, reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    officeConsumption: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const state = reactive({
      myComputed: computed(
        () => Math.round(props.officeConsumption)
      )
    })
    return {
      ...toRefs(state)
    }
  }
})
```

**2. Options API `computed`** (just like in Vue 2, it's still available):

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    officeConsumption: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    myComputed() {
      return Math.round(this.officeConsumption);
    }
  }
})
```

All of the above produce the same result. You can use `myComputed` in the `<template>`.

Comment: "will warn you when wrapping something that's not reactive" - didn't witness that. Is it a specific runtime warning? Any info on that?

Comment: @EstusFlask, I've just tested it on Vue SFC Playground with `computed(() => 'test')` and it's no longer issue-ing. I remember seeing it quite a few times in several apps. I'll remove it, anyways, as it doesn't appear to be true anymore. Thanks. I might run into it again in some app using an older `v3` version, I'll post a comment here with repro steps.